# How to implement encryption and decryption asymmetrically between client and server using openSSL library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openssl, public-key-encryption

I am trying to create a secure connection between a simple client and server application programed in ASP.NET and C#. I have to encrypt the messages exchanged between server and client. I have to apply integrity too, by using hash functions.

My question is how to parse the array of bytes exchanged and decrypt it.

Note: each message exchanged contains:

1. original message encrypted with public key of the destination
2. original message hashed (SH512) then encrypted with source private key

How to send and parse such an array of bytes?

Comment: Silly question, why not just rely on SSL (https) if you're alrady using an ASP.NET application (and presumably hosting it on a web server)?

Comment: i am trying to implement all of it, it is not silly

Comment: What are you using to communicate? Both ASMX and WCF services support message encryption and integrity with the proper setings

Comment: I am working in very low level, i am using socket

Comment: If you are working on low level, then why not just build your own server code instead of using ASP.NET? If you already have the Encrypt/decrypt methods down (if not, then it would be a good place to start), then just pass the bytes over the socket.

Comment: Don't you use the target's public key to encrypt instead of using the source's private key? If you encrypt using the private key, won't anyone be able to decrypt with the public key?

Comment: Even if you work at the socket level you can use SslStream on top of your socket which will establish SSL/TLS connection between your client and server. In cryptography/security it is always better to use proven solution instead of coming up with our own.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, asymmetric encryption is incredibly slow.  Most algorithms only use asymmetric encryption to perform a symmetric key exchange, then encrypt/decrypt everything with the symmetric key.